# Why Django redirects me to my api view after save a record with ajax?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I have a problem, I'm using Django with restframework to develop a school project but when I save a record with ajax this redirects me to the api page and not to the CRUD page, only admins can see the api page(view) so... Can you help me to resolve this?

this is my views.py

```
class pacientesList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Paciente.objects.all()
    serializer_class = pacienteSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = pacienteSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

and this is my ajax code to save data

```
$("#btnGuardarPaciente").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '{% url "core:pacientes_list" %}',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $("form").serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data); // only to see if this is working
            alert("Paciente agregado!.");
            $("#exampleModal").modal('toggle');

        },
        error: function(xhr, resp, text) {
            console.log(xhr, resp, text);
        }
    });
});
```

It's working fine, this save the record into db but only the problem is when I click on save button this redirects me to my api page and not to the CRUD page.

my html form

```
<form id="savePaciente" action="{% url 'core:pacientes_list' %}" method="post" >{%csrf_token%}
                        <md-form>
                            <input type="text" required name="first_name" 
                            class="form-control" id="id_first_name" placeholder="Nombre(s)">

                            <input type="text" required name="last_name" class="form-control"
                            id="id_last_name" placeholder="Apellidos">

                            <label for="id_gender">Selecciona el sexo</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="gender" id="id_gender" required>
                                <option value="F">Femenino</option>
                                <option value="M">Masculino</option>
                                <option value="O">Otro</option>
                            </select>
                     ........ 
                     ........
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" 
        id="btnGuardarPaciente">
                    </form>
```

and my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
    url(r'^historia-clinica/$', views.historiaClinicaView.as_view(), name='historia_clinica'),
    #url(r'^paciente-create/$', views.createPaciente, name='paciente_create'),
    #is this, the next url!
    url(r'^pacientes/$', views.pacientesList.as_view(), name='pacientes_list'),
    url(r'^paciente-detail/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.pacienteDetail.as_view(), name='paciente_detail'),
]
```

My CRUD is in /historia-clinica/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you put the save button in a html form with a defined `action`, so when you push it, there are two things happenning:

1. Your ajax code is excuted.
2. The web browser collects the form data, and POST it to the URL defined in form's `action`. This results a redirect.

You probably don't want the second case happen. Simply replace the `form` block with a `div`.

Comment: Yes that was my error, thank you!, now I put the save button into another div and make the js call.